# C++ arrays , and the "new" keyword

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

So I have this code in here I've try to create a 2-D array with different sizes,
first I declare 3 pointers then I assign different arrays to them and hope it works and it did well, but there is the problem , in the second code the compiler gives an error ( a value of type `int*` cannot be assigned to an entity type `int` )  so it means they are no longer pointers I think , but why is that , what am I missing here ? what is the biggest difference in these two codes other than one of them is declared in stack and other is on the heap

```
int main()
{
   int* arr[3];
   arr[0] = new int[5];
   arr[1] = new int[2];
   arr[2] = new int[6];

  delete[] arr[0];
  delete[] arr[1];
  delete[] arr[2];
}
```

//2nd Code

```
int main()
{
   int* arr = new int[3];
   arr[0] = new int[5];
   arr[1] = new int[2];
   arr[2] = new int[6];

}
```

and sorry for my baddd English

Comment: It would be `int** arr = new int*[3];`.

Comment: Don't do what you are doing now, and don't use nested vectors either, implement a proper 2d array instead. Read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30464186/3002139) for example.

Comment: @BaummitAugen: OP doesn't want a matrix from his snippet. so `vector<vector<int>>` seems the more appropriate here.

Comment: @Jarod42 Oh right. Poor reading on my part. Sorry to you and Ron.

Comment: @BaummitAugen Don't mention it. My now deleted comment was to use the vector of vectors.

Comment: Baum has a point there. If you are using the matrix then use his proposed solution.

Comment: Everyones' suggestions would be valid if this didn't sound like an assignment question to me.

Answer (score 1):

In the first program there is declared an array of pointers

```
int* arr[3];
```

In the second program there is allocated an array of integers

```
int* arr = new int[3];
```

So for example the expression

```
arr[0]
```

has type `int`.

If you want to allocate an array of pointers you should write

```
int ** arr = new int *[3];
    ^^               ^
```

In this case the expression

```
arr[0]
```

has type `int *` and you may write

```
arr[0] = new int[5];
```